# wave equation $C^2$ solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If we consider the wave equation on the half line $\mathbb{R}_+$ such that

$u_{tt} -u_{xx}=0$ in $\mathbb{R_+}\times(0,\infty)$

$u(x,0)=g(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=h(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R_+}$

$u(0,t)=0$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$

with $g(0)=0$, $h(0)=0$,

the solution is given by

1) $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[g(x+t)+g(x-t)]+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}h(y)\,dy$ for $x\geq t \geq 0$

2) $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[g(x+t)-g(t-x)]+\frac{1}{2}\int_{t-x}^{x+t}h(y)\,dy$ for $0\leq x \leq t$.

Why does Evans claim that $u$ does not belong to $C^2$ unless $g''(0)=0?$

I am not sure about how to proceed...certainly if I can show that $g$ and $\int_0^x h(t)\,dt$ are in $C^2$ then $u$ is also in $C^2$. And because we are unsure about the continuity of $g'$ and $g''$ at $0$ and of $h'$ at $0$ then it is worth investigating these functions at $0. But how do we calculate these?

Or do we return to how the solution was constructed which is via an odd reflection?
If $\tilde{u},\tilde{g},\tilde{h}$ are the odd reflections of $u,g,h$ then the solution is given by

$\tilde{u}=\frac{1}{2}[\tilde{g}(x+t)-\tilde{g}(x-t)] + \frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\tilde{h}(y)\,dy$ so it suffices to investigate under what conditions $\tilde{g}$ and $\int_0^x \tilde{h}(y)\,dy$ are $C^2$?

Help very much appreciated...

Comment: Look at what happens to $\partial^2_{xt}u$ on both $x>t$ and $x<t$ when you approach the diagonal $x=y$.